# How do I set user-session to gnome-classic in gdm3?

Tags: 16.04, gnome-classic

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.3.

I would like to to set the user-session to *gnome-classic*.

By default it is set to gnome.

I have added `user-session=gnome-classic` to `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` but this has not changed the default user session.

Comment: I have selected the gnome-classic in the greeter session before logging in also. It is not remembering the last used session. It just goes to gnome session even if I choose gnome-classic session.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /etc/alternatives/x-session-manager gnome-session-classic /usr/bin/gnome-session-classic 99
```

and

```
cd /usr/share/xsessions
sudo mv gnome.desktop gnome.desktop-orig
```

has done the trick.